# PyQt5 keyPressEvent blocks reading keys by QWebView page

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to set `Escape` key as one that exits application

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
```

but when I do that QWebView loses keyboard events.

```
class PlayFlash(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        # QWebView
        self.view = QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.resize(1024, 768)
        self.move(0, 0)
        # enable flashplayer plugin
        self._settings = QWebSettings.globalSettings()
        self._settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.load("file:///home/kamil/gitlab/PlayFlash/PlayFlash.html")
```

If I don't use `keyPressEvent` at all, keyboard events are read by QWebView page.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You should call the base implementation if you are not handling other keys: add `else:` `super().keyPressEvent(event)`.

Comment: @musicamante That's exactly what I needed! So if I'm understanding correctly without using ```super``` function gets overloaded and all other events are lost?

Comment: Whenever you *override* a function, you are *overriding* its behavior. If you want to do what the default implementation does, you *must* call the `super()` function within that override, otherwise it will do nothing at all, except for what you are already doing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.restoreMainMenu()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```